# Python Regex Substitution

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a regular expression to replace My_String with the new ModuleId:

```
My_String = '_test --fid --ModuleId 0x51900879 -- p'
Module_Id = 0x87400271
```

So the final outcome should be following:

```
Result-String = '_test --fid --ModuleId 0x87400271 -- p'
```

I need a regex like following but without hardcoding the id 0x51900879

My_String = re.sub("ModuleId 0x51900879", "ModuleId M_id", My_String)

Comment: Do you know what the regex syntax for "a digit" is? And for "_n_ of the preceding thing"?

Comment: Python documentation for `re` is here https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=regex and the regex howto is here https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto- and why don’t you read then try for yourself e.g. on regex101.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a example using `re.sub` and int conversion to hex string:

```
import re

My_String = '_test --fid --ModuleId 0x51900879 -- p'
Module_Id = 0x87400271
re.sub('0x\d{8}', '0x%0.2X' % Module_Id, My_String)
```

output: `'_test --fid --ModuleId 0x87400271 -- p'`